# Anaconda prompt launches Visual Studio 2017 when run .py Files

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

Traditionally I've used `Notepad ++` along with the `Anaconda` prompt to write and run scripts locally on my Windows PC.

I had my PC upgraded and thought I'd give `Virtual Studio Code` a chance to see if I liked it.

Now, every time I try to execute a `.py` file in the `Anaconda` prompt `Visual Studio 2017` launches.  I hate this and can't figure out how to stop it.

I've tried the following:

1. Uninstalling `Virtual Studio Code`.
2. Changing environments in `Anaconda`.
3. Reinstalling `Anaconda`.  I did not check the box for the `%PATH` option.
4. Reboots at every step.

On my `Windows 10` laptop `Visual Studio 2017` doesn't appear in my `Apps and Features` to uninstall.  I've tried Googling and am stuck.

The programs involved are:

`Windows 10 Professional`

`Visual Studio 2017`

`Anaconda` version `2019.10` Build Channel `py37_0`

Can someone help me figure out how to stop this?

Comment: I would suggest right clicking on the '.py' file and selecting 'open with' there you can set up your default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How were you running the scripts before? `python script.py` or only `script.py`?

If it is the latter, what happened probably is that Windows has associated `.py` files to Visual Studio. Right click on the file, go to `Open With`, then select Python if you want to run them, or Notepad++ if you want to edit them.